# Remove Invocation Requirement for Alpha Released Google Home Action

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Can a private, [alpha released](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments), action remove the need to use the phrase "talk to [my app]" in invocation?

For example, is it possible to invoke the action by saying:

*"Ok Google, tell me my agenda."* Automatically invoking the private action.

In contrast to, *"Hey Google, **tell My App to** tell me my agenda."*

Implicit invocation seemed promising, but further research made me think it was just a way for Google to suggest your app to a user. Am I mistaken in this interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit invocation is a feature, similar to [built-in intents](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/built-in-intents) to invoke an action directly without the **talk to my app** prefix. These features should work for public as well as alpha release actions.

I don't know if agenda specifically will be supported, as that is something that can be handled directly by the Google Assistant, but a query like **play a game** will suggest your alpha released action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For clarification, will implicit invocation actually invoke my action or merely suggest a phrase my user should use to my invoke my action? The diagram at the top of [this page](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit) suggests that Google suggests the user what to say and does not actually invoke my action.

Comment: So I've managed to invoke it sometimes like this. Me: "How do I say HELLO in the phonetic alphabet?" GA: "Ok, for that you may want to talk to Phonetic Alphabet. Want to give it a try?" Me: "Yeah" GA: "Okay, getting phonetic alphabet. *boop boop*" PA: "HELLO is Hotel..."

Comment: Awesome ok that helps to clarify. Thanks again for replying!